# Google APIs explorer quota exceeded

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

When using the Google APIs explorer with the YouTube Data API, it is giving this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.quota",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>."
 }
}
```

It works fine if I enter my own OAUTH2 client id, so I think the quota has been exceeded for the API explorer's API key, and Google needs to increase its quota.

Comment: I guess you'd better let Google know then.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted here. https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support

Comment: And I do understand that google's support policy conflicts with stack overflow's rules (https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). However, given that there is no way to contact google about bugs like this (they just tell us to post here), leaving the question here for other users would seem to be the best (bad) option.

Comment: I'll reopen, with some reservations.  You can read more about them here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207634/is-there-any-official-google-support-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Waiting until the next morning resolved the issue (at least temporarily), as the quotas reset each day. The bug has been reported to Google.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Waiting will often resolve this issue, as a high number of users exploring this API may have that effect. But the project owner can also request more quota for high-usage projects.